# Excel VBA - Move cursor to Next Page

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox containing names of Sheets. I need to merge all those sheets into a Single sheet and save it as PDF.

I need know 1st Row number of next page. Please see below code and comment in it:

```
 For i = 0 To lstPrintSheet.ListCount - 1
        Set oFindRange = WS_Print.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If oFindRange Is Nothing Then
            pRow = 1
        Else
            pRow = oFindRange.Row + 1
        End If

        ' instead of above logic, I want to assign pRow with the 1st Row on the next page.
        ' So suppose after pasting the contents, if my last used row in WS_Print is 255 on page# 4, I want pRow to assign to 1st row of page# 5 (So that next sheet gets pasted on next page)

        On Error Resume Next
            Do

                Err.Clear
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(lstPrintSheet.List(i)).UsedRange.Copy WS_Print.Range("A" & pRow)
                pRow = pRow + 1

            Loop While Err.Number <> 0
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next
```

Any Expert Advice for this please?